# Does it matter what order I play the campaigns in?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

Is there any reason to play the campaigns in a particular order, or should I just pick whichever one strikes my fancy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no benefit to playing the campaigns in a specific order. (Aside from the tutorial campaign, of course)

There *is* however, minor benefits from finishing the five "standard" campaigns before taking on the "final" campaign: since you must pick a hero from one of the finished campaigns for the final campaign, finishing more campaigns gives you a greater pantheon of heroes to pick from.

That said, there is nothing particularly relevant about beating one of the 5 standard campaigns before another.

Pick your favorite!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the Stronghold campaign first, as it is the easiest, followed by Sanctuary, Haven, and Inferno. Ending with necropolis , which is by far the hardest.

Answer (score -3):

- Heart of Nightmares (Collectors' edition map)
- Prologue 1
- Prologue 2
- Stronghold 1
- Sanctuary 1
- Inferno 1
- Haven 1
- Necropolis 1
- Stronghold 2
- Sanctuary 2
- Haven 2
- Necropolis 2
- Sanctuary 3
- Stronghold 3
- Inferno 2
- Necropolis 3
- Inferno 3
- Sanctuary 4
- Stronghold 4
- Haven 3
- Necropolis 4
- Haven 4
- Inferno 4
- Epilogues

Comment: And... why this order?